# JavaScript - convert large object in an array to an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects

I have an array which contains one object:

```
[
    {
        value 0: "value", 
        value 1: "value", 
        value 2: "value", 
        value 3: "value", 
        value 4: "value", 
        value 5: "value", 
        value 6: "value", 
        value 7: "value", 
        value 8: "value", 
        value 9: "value"
    }
]
```

Ideally I need it to look more like this:

```
[
    {
        value 0: "value"
    },
    {
        value 1: "value"
    },
    {
        value 2: "value"
    },
    ...
]
```

If its possible I would also like to replace the keys of the objects so that they are all the same.

Is there a way that I can do this with JavaScript?

Examples would be much appreciated!

Thanks for your time

Comment: The given array and the expected array. both are looking same

Comment: I hope those aren't you real property names -- they are invalid without quotes

Comment: yes, there is a way. Have you tried looping through the single item properties and inserting into a new array of objects for each property ?

Comment: If the content of your object is a string you can use the split method.

Comment: Your initial array produces an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number`...

Comment: Those aren't the actual values, it was just for illustrative purposes but the idea was to split one large object into an array of smaller objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All objects have the key named "value". Change it to whatever you need.

```
var out = Object.keys(arr[0]).map(function (el) {
  return { value: arr[0][el] };
});
```

This grabs the keys from the object, and using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/maphttps://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), returns a new array populated with objects using the values from the original object's key/value pairs.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ngbs4Lfe/)

Answer (score 0):

You can map keys of first object in array (using ECMAScript 2015):

```
var data = [{
    'value 0': 'value',
    'value 1': 'value',
    'value 2': 'value',
    'value 3': 'value',
    'value 4': 'value',
    'value 5': 'value',
    'value 6': 'value',
    'value 7': 'value',
    'value 8': 'value',
    'value 9': 'value'
}];

var first = data[0];
var result = Object.keys(first).map(key => ({ [key]: first[key] }));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be solved by using `forEach` and `map`:

```
var result = []
arrayOfObjects.forEach(function(object) {
  result = result.concat(Object.keys(object).map(function(key) {
    return {
      value: object[key]
    }
  }))
})
console.log(result)
```

...or with plain loops:

```
var result = []
for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfObjects.length; i++) {
  var object = arrayOfObjects[i]
  for (var key in object) {
    result.push({
      value: object[key]
    })
  }
}
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

A proposal with ES5

```js
function format(object, array) {
    Object.keys(object).forEach(function (k) {
        var o = {};
        o[k] = object[k];
        array.push(o);
    });
}

var data = [{ 'value 0': "value", 'value 1': "value", 'value 2': "value", 'value 3': "value", 'value 4': "value", 'value 5': "value", 'value 6': "value", 'value 7': "value", 'value 8': "value", 'value 9': "value" }],
    formated = [];

format(data[0], formated)
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(formated, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```